# C++ need to search doc for string then ignore all but part numbers

Tags: c++

I'd like to write a C++ program to open a .txt file and search ignoring all text until it finds the string "partNumberHere"{1305001}".{"1647823},"{1984395}

I'm having problems finding what I should use. I've used cin.ignore() before but only to ignore a number of characters or until hitting a certain character.

So I need to know what command to search the text file for PartnumberHere.  Once the appropriate text is found i need to ignore various special characters(",{-) and only capture the number.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can research things like `stringstream` and `substr`. If using C++ is not a requirement, you can possibly create a shell script using UNIX utilities such as `grep`, `cut` or `awk` to capture these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line until you find that particular line.

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream fin("filename.txt");

while(std::getline(fin,line))
{
   if(line.find("partNumberHere") != std::string::npos)
      break;
}
 fin.close();
/*
variable line contains your required partNumberHere line
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! The only part i didn't understand was "!= std::string::npos" what does this part do? Also, once the program finds the partnumber text how can I store the numbers into int values while ignoring the special characters?

Comment: @user2832891 `std::string::npos` is returned when no match is found, refer [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), regarding number extraction you can give a try to [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), come back again if you're lost ;)